# Article class: avoid page break after appendix title

Tags: page-breaking, appendices

I am using the article class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

With this setup, I am trying to add an appendix after the bibliography:

```
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\pagebreak %or actually any other command for starting on a new page (newpage, clearpage)
%appendix title
%appendix content
```

The appendix starts on a new page. However, it should also have a title displayed on the same page. I have tried a wide choice of commands to have the appendix title on the same page, but nothing works. Anything I do sets the appendix title to a new page and the appendix content on yet another page. I want a new page after the bib and the appendix title and content should both be on that new page. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
anne

Comment: Did you try `\clearpage\section{Appendix}`? Note that you should use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` together with the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Also not related, but it's generally good practice to load `hyperref` package last.

Comment: Yes, of course I have tried the obvious things ^^. `\section` works as desired in the body of my article (inline sectioning), but after the bib it creates a pagebreak.

Comment: Also not related: You appear to be using three [3!] deprecated packages. (1) Instead of `subfigure`, use either `subfig` or `subcaption`. (2) Instead of `latexsym`, use `amssymb`. (3) Instead of `times`, use `newtxtext`.

Answer (score 1):

I have given up on solving this, but I can share an alternative solution. Instead of making a section title, I marked my content as appendix in the caption (since my appendix content is actually a table). This is what I did:

In the preamble: `\usepackage{caption}`
After the bib:

```
\captionsetup{type=table}
\captionsetup{name=\textbf{Appendix}}
```

Within my table environment:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textbf{\Alph{table}}}
\addtocounter{table}{-3}
```

Produces this without creating ugly blanks:

[image]

Cheers,
a

Comment: you didn't say in your original question that the content of your appindix is a table,  tables float, and depending on the size of the table, there may not be enough space left on the page after the section title to accommodate it, hence the new page.  but without example code to experiment with, anything we can do would just be a guess.